# Android: measureText on Paint object for italic rendered fonts

Tags: android

I need to compute the lengths in pixels for all the texts provided by my client.
The problem is they provided only one regular font and the italic style has to be rendered by Android. A known Android bug is that for italic (rendered as italic) fonts, the width of TextView is not correctly computed and the end of text is cut.

Do you have any idea on how to compute the length of these italic texts correctly?

So far I've tried measureText and getTextWidths methods, but I think that the bug is somewhere in the Android sources because the length of italic and normal texts are the same.

I found that when there is no italic font and it has to be rendered, then in the TextView source code, on TextPaint object skewX parameter is set. Its value is -0.25f.

Do you know what is this parameter and maybe how to calculate the missing pixels based on this skewX factor?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a thin space `"\u2009"` to measure the text. Then trim it before drawing it. Align the text center might give best result.